# 3D object from vertices array

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I have recently started working in Kivy, and am trying to familiarize myself with it's capabilities. I have been looking through Kivy's API Reference, but found it not so useful.
The only useful example of 3D rendering I found is the one that already comes with Kivy and my lack of understanding it makes it good only for .obj files. What I'm trying to accomplish is a 3D object whose vertices are generated on the fly and stored into `self.field.vertices` array.

I attempted to modify the code, but I don't know what to do here. The code in `main.py` is almost identical to the example provided with installation, so this is only the relevant part - the one I'm having trouble with.

```
def setup_scene(self):
    Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
    PushMatrix()
    Translate(0, 0, -3)
    self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
    UpdateNormalMatrix()
    self.mesh = Mesh(
        vertices = self.field.vertices,
        indices = range(len(self.field.vertices)//8), #no idea why this is so
        fmt = [(b"v_pos", 3, "float"), (b"v_normal", 3, "float"), (b"v_tc0", 2, "float")],
        #fmt value was copy-pasted from example's value. No idea what this is.
        mode = "triangles",
    )
    PopMatrix()
```

Can somebody please explain what value should be in `fmt`, and what is happening here in general? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> The only useful example of 3D rendering I found is the one that already comes with Kivy and my lack of understanding it makes it good only for .obj files.

Be aware that the reason for the lack of documentation is that kivy simply doesn't focus on that right now. The backend supports some fairly impressive and generic stuff, and some people are working with this (some of which may find its way to kivy master), but you'll probably need some general knowledge and understanding of what it's doing if you want to do serious 3D stuff with kivy.

Anyway, what's really happening is that this code is passing vertices to the opengl vertex shader, and the various parameters correspond to things in that shader. The setup for this takes place elsewhere in the code - if you look, you'll notice the use of a RenderContext rather than a plain Canvas as widgets normally have, and also a special opengl command to enable the depth buffer.

The fmt is the vertex format directly - the attributes that each vertex will have in opengl terms. You can see in the `simple.glsl` file in the example that each of the parameters corresponds to an `attribute` in the shader, and are used in the maths to manipulate where the vertex will appear on your screen. Actually, `v_tc0` doesn't appear...I guess it's not actually necessary.

> Can somebody please explain what value should be in fmt

I don't know, it depends on the nature of the data you pass in and the exact error you get. If you mean in the general sense, the important thing is that it works with the vertex shader as above.

Either way, what's really important is you need some understanding of opengl, and of how kivy's api wraps it. http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ is a good tutorial covering the general ideas, and it will also help to make use of kivy in general and to check out advanced examples like those working with shaders.

There's also some other stuff on 3d with kivy, though bear in mind what I said above. nskrypnik has been working on a full 3d framework, [github here](https://github.com/nskrypnik/kivy3), though I don't know his development status and you'll still need some knowledge to dive in. He also has some other examples using 3d, and there are other examples around such as tito's [3d inspector demo](https://gist.github.com/tito/5411449) (and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2p-2jq5tXIw)).

Comment: I didn't really look through `simple.glsl`, now it seems to me that fmt value (without `v_tc0`) is correct. After the application enters mainloop, I get `Exception TypeError: 'a float is required' in 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Mesh.build' ignored`, and a blank screen. Vertices are passed in exactly the same format as they are in example (a tuple of tuples). What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying the example doesn't work, or it does but you made some changes that don't?

Comment: The example works. But when I change vertices to `self.field.vertices` , and change the range of indices, I get an empty window with and the console prints out the exception above. Nothing else was changed.